# I am trying make a listbox item store information

Tags: c#, listbox

I am trynig to make a battle Tracker for DND. I have a listbox and I am trying to make a way for the items in the listbox save information in other Textboxes, comboboxes, and check boxes.

I have no training in C# or code. I have tried searching and searching for some kind of answer but i can find none. Can someone helps or am i trying to do this the hard way and there is an easier way.

I have made it so when i click on an item i the listbox it clears all the comboboxes, listboxes, and checkboxes.  i just need to make the values save and reappear when the listbox item has been clicked again.

private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

```
        string curItem = FighterNames.SelectedItem.ToString();

        switch (curItem)
        {
            case "1":
                BasicStatACP.Visible = false;
               
                break;
            case "2":
                ASIP.Visible = false;
                ASIP.Visible = true;
                break;
            case "3":
                ResistanceP.Visible = false;
                ResistanceP.Visible = true;
                break;
        }

        ///Clear Text Boxs in Stats and Immmunities on Clicking Name in Listbox
        InitTB.Clear(); ACTB.Clear(); SRTB.Clear(); TouchTB.Clear(); FlatFootedTB.Clear(); RefTB.Clear(); 
        FortTB.Clear(); WillTB.Clear(); DRTB.Clear(); STRTB.Clear(); DEXTB.Clear(); CONTB.Clear(); 
        WISTB.Clear(); INTTB.Clear(); CHATB.Clear(); SpeedTB.Clear(); GrappleTB.Clear(); FireTB.Clear();
        ColdTB.Clear(); AcidTB.Clear();PoisonTB.Clear(); ForceTB.Clear(); OtherNameTB.Clear();
        OtherNumberTB.Clear();

        ///Clear Text Boxs in Attack One on Clicking Name in Listbox
        Attk1NameTB.Clear(); Attk1BonusTB.Clear(); Attk1DMGTB.Clear(); Attk1EffectTB.Clear(); 
        Attk1SaveTB.Clear(); Attk1CritRangeTB.Clear(); Attk1CritDMGDiceTB.Clear(); Attk1ExtraTB.Clear();
        Attk1RangeTB.Clear();

        ///Clear Text Boxs in Off Hand on Clicking Name in Listbox
        Attk2NameTB.Clear(); Attk2BonusTB.Clear(); Attk2DMGTB.Clear(); Attk2EffectTB.Clear();
        Attk2SaveTB.Clear(); Attk2CritRangeTB.Clear(); Attk2CritDMGDiceTB.Clear(); Attk2ExtraTB.Clear();
        Attk2RangeTB.Clear();

        ///Clear Text Boxs in Extra Attack One on Clicking Name in Listbox
        Attk3NameTB.Clear(); Attk3BonusTB.Clear(); Attk3DMGTB.Clear(); Attk3EffectTB.Clear();
        Attk3SaveTB.Clear(); Attk3CritRangeTB.Clear(); Attk3CritDMGDiceTB.Clear(); Attk3ExtraTB.Clear();
        Attk3RangeTB.Clear();

        ///Clear Text Boxs in Attack Two on Clicking Name in Listbox
        Attk4NameTB.Clear(); Attk4BonusTB.Clear(); Attk4DMGTB.Clear(); Attk4EffectTB.Clear();
        Attk4SaveTB.Clear(); Attk4CritRangeTB.Clear(); Attk4CritDMGDiceTB.Clear(); Attk4ExtraTB.Clear();
        Attk4RangeTB.Clear();

        ///Clear Text Boxes in Skill on Clicking Name in Listbox
        BalanceTB.Clear(); BluffTB.Clear(); ConcentrationTB.Clear(); DipTB.Clear(); DisguiseTB.Clear();
        EscapeTB.Clear(); HideTB.Clear(); IntimidateTB.Clear(); JumpTB.Clear(); ListenTB.Clear(); MSTB.Clear();
        RideTB.Clear(); SearchTB.Clear(); SMTB.Clear(); SHTB.Clear(); SCTB.Clear(); SpotTB.Clear(); 
        SurTB.Clear(); SwimTB.Clear(); TumTB.Clear(); RopeTB.Clear();

        ///Clear Text Boxes in Health Bar on Clicking Name in Listbox
        HealthChangeTB.Clear(); HPTB.Clear(); MaxHPTB.Clear();

        ///Clear Text Boxes in Continued Status Damage on Clicking Name in Listbox
        BurnDPSTB.Clear(); AcidDPSTB.Clear(); ColdDPSTB.Clear(); PoisonDPSTB.Clear(); BleedDPSTB.Clear();
        OtherDPSTB.Clear();

        ///Clear Combo Box in Stats and Immmunities on Clicking Name in Listbox
        DRCB.ResetText(); FireCB.ResetText(); AcidCB.ResetText(); ColdCB.ResetText(); PosionCB.ResetText();
        ForceCB.ResetText(); OtherCB.ResetText(); 

        ///Clear Combo Boxes in Attack One on Clicking Name in Listbox
        Attk1TypeCB.ResetText(); Attk1EffectCB.ResetText(); Attk1EffectTimeCB.ResetText(); Attk1SaveCB.ResetText();
        Attk1CritMultplyCB.ResetText(); Attk1CritEffectCB.ResetText(); Attk1CritTypeCB.ResetText(); Attk1RangeCB.ResetText(); Attk1RangeTypeCB.ResetText();

        ///Clear Combo Boxes in Attack Two on Clicking Name in Listbox
        Attk2TypeCB.ResetText(); Attk2EffectCB.ResetText(); Attk2EffectTimeCB.ResetText(); Attk2SaveCB.ResetText();
        Attk2CritMultplyCB.ResetText(); Attk2CritEffectCB.ResetText(); Attk2CritTypeCB.ResetText(); Attk2RangeCB.ResetText(); Attk2RangeTypeCB.ResetText();

        ///Clear Combo Boxes in Attack Three on Clicking Name in Listbox
        Attk3TypeCB.ResetText(); Attk3EffectCB.ResetText(); Attk3EffectTimeCB.ResetText(); Attk3SaveCB.ResetText();
        Attk3CritMultplyCB.ResetText(); Attk3CritEffectCB.ResetText(); Attk3CritTypeCB.ResetText(); Attk3RangeCB.ResetText(); Attk3RangeTypeCB.ResetText();

        ///Clear Combo Boxes in Attack Four on Clicking Name in Listbox
        Attk4TypeCB.ResetText(); Attk4EffectCB.ResetText(); Attk4EffectTimeCB.ResetText(); Attk4SaveCB.ResetText();
        Attk4CritMultplyCB.ResetText(); Attk4CritEffectCB.ResetText(); Attk4CritTypeCB.ResetText(); Attk4RangeCB.ResetText(); Attk4RangeTypeCB.ResetText();

        ///Clear Combo Box in Conditions on Clicking Name in Listbox
        BlindCheck.Checked = false; ConfusedCheck.Checked = false; ConfusedCheck.Checked = false; ; DazzledCheck.Checked = false;
        DazeCheck.Checked = false; ; CoweringCheck.Checked = false; ; DeafCheck.Checked = false; EntangleCheck.Checked = false; FascinateCheck.Checked = false;
        FrightCheck.Checked = false; NauseateCheck.Checked = false; PanicCheck.Checked = false; 
        ParalyzeCheck.Checked = false; PetrtfyCHECK.Checked = false; ; ShakenCheck.Checked = false; SickCheck.Checked = false; 
        StunCheck.Checked = false;

        ///Clear Check Boxes in Skill on Clicking Name in Listbox
        BalCB.Checked = false; BluCB.Checked = false; ConCB.Checked = false; DipCB.Checked = false;
        DisCB.Checked = false; EscCB.Checked = false; HideCB.Checked = false; IntCB.Checked = false;
        JumpCB.Checked = false; ListenCB.Checked = false; MoveSilentlyCB.Checked = false; RideCB.Checked = false;
        SearchCB.Checked = false; SenseMotiveCB.Checked = false; SlightHandCB.Checked = false;
        SpellcraftCB.Checked = false; SpotCB.Checked = false; SurvivalCB.Checked = false; SwimCB.Checked = false;
        TumbleCB.Checked = false; RopeCB.Checked = false;

        ///Clear Combo Boxes in Health Bar on Clicking Name in Listbox
        BurnDpsCheck.Checked = false; AcidDpsCheck.Checked = false; ColdDpsCheck.Checked = false; 
        PosionDpsCheck.Checked = false; BleedDpsCheck.Checked = false; OtherDPSCheck.Checked = false;

        ///Clear NuimericUpDopwn On Clicking Listbox Name
        BlindNUM.Value = 0; ConfusedNUM.Value = 0; DazzledNUM.Value = 0; DeafNUM.Value = 0; EntangleNUM.Value = 0; FascinateNUM.Value = 0;
        FrightNUM.Value = 0; NauseateNUM.Value = 0; PanicNUM.Value = 0; ParalyzeNUM.Value = 0; ShakenNUM.Value = 0; SickNUM.Value = 0;
        StunNUM.Value = 0; BurnNUM.Value = 0; AcidNUM.Value = 0; BleedNUM.Value = 0;
        PoisonNUM.Value = 0; ColdNUM.Value = 0; OtherNUM.Value = 0;
```

Comment: can you share what you have tried

Comment: Just edited it with all the code i have for it, and that i am trying. the first bit I am trying to see if   i could do it  by instead hiding and showing panels.... but I can make them dissapear and not reappear.

Comment: I suspect data binding would reduce this to about 3 lines of code

Comment: @Zakarhyn this is out of scope of the actual question, but start looking into polymorphism. Group your Objects or try to generify them, then you could do something in the lines of `ObjectGroup.disable()` where the implementation iterates over all the objects en sets them `false` or whatever. Good luck! :)

Comment: @CaiusJard How would I do that. I am completely new to coding